# How do I save the foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-uploads

I want to upload multiple images.

```
class IssuePanel(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(ComicIssue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    panel = models.FileField(upload_to='comic_issues_files/panels/')
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

After following the examples on django-multiupload's repository on github, I have this on forms.py

```
class PanelsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model = ComicIssue
    fields = ('issue', 'issue_title', 'issue_cover', 'issue_description', 'issue_cover', 'issue_file')

panels = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=20, max_file_size=2048*2048*5)

def save(self, commit=False):
    instance = super(PanelsForm, self).save()
    for each in self.cleaned_data['panels']:
        IssuePanel.objects.create(panel=each, issue=instance)
    return instance
```

views.py

```
class ComicIssueCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ComicIssue
    slug_field = 'comicseries_id'
    form_class = PanelsForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.title = ComicSeries.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return redirect('comics:series_detail', pk=obj.title.id, slug=obj.title.slug)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^comic/issue/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add/$', views.ComicIssueCreate.as_view(), name='comic-issue-add'),
```

However, I get this error 
IntegrityError at /comic/issue/21/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: comics_comicissue.title_id

```
class ComicIssue(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Uploaded by: '
    )
title = models.ForeignKey(ComicSeries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Series Title')
issue = models.CharField(verbose_name='Issue Number', max_length=500)
issue_title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Issue Title', max_length=1000)
issue_cover = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Issue cover', upload_to='comic_issues', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
issue_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
issue_file = models.FileField(verbose_name='Issue file', upload_to='comic_issues_files', max_length=100,
    help_text='File in pdf or as single image', null=True, blank=True
)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
issue_slug = models.SlugField(default='')

class Meta:

    verbose_name = 'Comic Issue'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Comic Issues'

def __str__(self):
    return '{}: {} issue number - {}'.format(self.title.title, self.issue_title, self.issue)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.issue_slug = slugify(self.issue_title)
    super(ComicIssue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('comics:issue_detail', kwargs={'issue_slug':self.issue_slug,'pk': self.pk})
```

Could this function in the ComicIssue model be a problem since it is also highlighted on the error page:

```
def save(self, commit=False, *args, **kwargs):
        self.issue_slug = slugify(self.issue_title)
        super(ComicIssue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am passing the title_id from the url. It is working on other models just not this one. How do I save the foreign key?

Comment: Can you show the `ComicIssue` model? That's where the error occurs (on `instance = super(PanelsForm, self).save()`). The error is complaining about a missing `title_id` field, which indeed isn't defined in your form.

Comment: Also side note: There shouldn't be a `commit` parameter in your model's `save()` method. That's only for ModelForms.

Comment: The title_id is passed from the url. This method is working on other views and models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving your form in the form's `save` method regardless of the `commit` value. The first line is `instance = super(PanelsForm, self).save()` which will try to save a `ComicIssue` instance even though in your view, you wrote `obj = form.save(commit=False)`.

You can do two things: pass the `title` and `user` to your form at init so the form can handle assigning those during save. Or change your form's `save` method to:

```
def save(self, commit=False):
    instance = super(PanelsForm, self).save(commit=commit)
    if commit:
        for each in self.cleaned_data['panels']:
            IssuePanel.objects.create(panel=each, issue=instance)
    return instance
```

And then your view needs to call the form's `save()` method twice (note that the form's `instance` is passed by reference, so changing it in the view also changes the form's `instance`):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.title = ComicSeries.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    obj.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('comics:series_detail', pk=obj.title.id, slug=obj.title.slug)
```